# How can i forward http request to https?

Tags: apache, http, https, ubuntu-18.04, forward

I have an application that work on :
http://XXXXX.it:8080/calendar

But i need to redirect it to
https_//XXXX.it/calendar

I install apache2 and add the certificate on it.

here the info:

**etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080

<VirtualHost *:80 *:8080>
ServerName calendar.XXXXX.it
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/XXXXXit.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/p-key.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/XXXXXit-chain.crt

SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
Redirect permanent / https://calendar.XXXXX.it/
</VirtualHost>
```

**etc/apache2/site-available/default-ssl.conf**

```
# NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/XXXXXit-chain.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/p-key.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/private/XXXXXXit.crt

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
                RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName 10.160.10.101
#       ServerName calendar.lantechlongwave.it
        ProxyPass               /calendar http://localhost:8080/calendar
        ProxyPassReverse        /calendar http://localhost:8080/calendar


        ProxyPass               http://calendar.XXXXXX.it:8080/calendar https://calendar.XXXX.it/calendar
        ProxyPassReverse        http://calendar.XXXXXX.it:8080/calendar https://calendar.XXXXX.it/calendar

        ProxyPass               /old/calendar http://localhost:8080/old/calendar
        ProxyPassReverse        /old/calendar http://localhost:8080/old/calendar

        ProxyPass               /socket.io      http://localhost:8080/socket.io
        ProxyPassReverse        /socket.io      http://localhost:8080/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
#Listen 443

Listen 80

#Listen 8080
<IfModule ssl_module>
       Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
       Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/proxy.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

        # If you want to use apache2 as a forward proxy, uncomment the
        # 'ProxyRequests On' line and the <Proxy *> block below.
        # WARNING: Be careful to restrict access inside the <Proxy *> block.
        # Open proxy servers are dangerous both to your network and to the
        # Internet at large.
        #
        # If you only want to use apache2 as a reverse proxy/gateway in
        # front of some web application server, you DON'T need
        # 'ProxyRequests On'.

        ProxyRequests On
        <Proxy *>
           AddDefaultCharset off
           Require all denied
           Require local
        </Proxy>

        # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
        # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
        # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block
        #ProxyVia Off

</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/forward_proxy.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
 # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
 # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
 # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
 # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
 # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
 # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
 #ServerName www.example.com
ProxyRequests On
 ProxyVia On
<Proxy "*">
 Require ip 10.101
 </Proxy>
# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
 # error, crit, alert, emerg.
 # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
 # modules, e.g.
 #LogLevel info ssl:warn
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_forward_proxy.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_forward_proxy.log combined
# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
 # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
 # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
 # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
 # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
 #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

But don't work, because if i put the url http://XXXXX.it:8080/calendar on my browser they work in http and don't forward on https.
If i try to put https://XXXXX.it/calendar they don't work!

Comment: You can't have both http and https site on the same port

Comment: ok, i know that but how can i forward the httpurl to the https ?